# How to upgrade Sencha Touch from 2.0.1.1 to 2.4?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to know if is possible to update a project done with Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1 to Sencha Touch 2.4.

Any idea is welcome thanks!

Comment: (1) Backup
(2) `sencha app upgrade /path/to/touch_2.4`
(3) Test.

Comment: Make sure to read the changeLog from 2.1 and 2.3. Some components got a major rewrite (e.g. list, database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to run a command line from your project folder:

```
sencha app upgrade <Path to Sencha Touch 2.4 SDK>
```

I hope this will help you.

------------ EDIT ---------------

Make sure:

1) You are running this command from inside the project folder.

2) Cross check the path mentioned.

Comment: Gives me this error, any help ?

sencha app upgrade D:\Sencha_SDK\touch-2.4.0\

Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.Version.cleanVersionString(Version.java:169)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$UpgradeCommand.execute(AppCommands.ja
va:216)

Comment: Make sure: 
1) You are running this command from inside the project folder.
2) Cross check the path mentioned.

Comment: That was correct, I had to change the env variable plus run it from the project folder instead of the mobile folder - thanks for you help

Comment: That is the most common mistake that we forgot to run this command from inside the project folder. Anyways, you are welcome. :)