# Sencha App Upgrade Issue: Must be run from App folder

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

I am trying to run an update of an old Sencha Touch app using Sencha CMD, however when I try to run it from the App folder (which I assume is right due to it having all the requirements) I am getting an error returned:

"[ERR] Command must be run from an app folder"

Here's the contents of the folder where I am executing the command:

[folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuAz1.png)

Comment: This is also not allowing me to build from here either

Comment: Can you post your App touch version, Cmd version and also if you can build the App or use any other sencha commands there?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099278/how-to-upgrade-sencha-touch-from-2-0-1-1-to-2-4/26101538#26101538

Comment: Where is your ".sencha" folder? Why do you have "Views" in the root and not inside "app/views"? Why is "App" written with capital A? Where is your "app.json" file and the "boostrap.js" and "bootstrap.json".

Answer (score 2):

"[ERR] Command must be run from an app folder"

This error means that .sencha folder is missing in directory, So check properly and add it.

Answer (score 0):

you're not in the sencha app project folder inside. you need to run that command inside the sencha app folder.